# HttpServlet web service crashes at doGet but works with main method in Eclipse

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets

So I wrote a Web Service using HttpServlet in Java, and this Web Service has to return a list of vehicles to whatever application calls for it. The list of `Vehicles` is obtained calling a static method that creates a Hibernate session, obtains the vehicle list from the database, and returns it to the caller.

If I run this as a main method in the Servlet class, it works wonderfully. However, if I put the same code in the `doGet()` method, I have an exception happening.

Here's the code:

The Servlet class (this works, as a main method ran in Eclipse):

```
public static void main(String[]a){
        //obtain the list of vehicles from the database
        List<Vehicle> vehicles = ExecuteVehicle.getVehicleList();
        for (Vehicle vehicle:vehicles){
            System.out.println(vehicle.getVehicleId());
        }
    }
```

This is the `getVehicleList()` method:

```
public static List<Vehicle> getVehicleList(){

        //open a Session
        Session session = HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        //start a transaction
        session.beginTransaction();

        //SELECT STATEMENT for the entire list of Vehicles
        Query<Vehicle> query = session.getNamedQuery("SelectAllVehicles"); //query name is declared in the mapping file
        List<Vehicle> vehicles = query.list();

        //commit the changes and end the transaction
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        //close the Session
        session.close();

        //close the SessionFactory
        HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().close();

        return vehicles;

    }
```

And this is the `doGet()` method in the Servlet class that crashes, if you try to actually run it as a Web Service:

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        //obtain the list of vehicles from the database
        List<Vehicle> vehicles = ExecuteVehicle.getVehicleList();

        //start writing a stream of data
        resp.setContentType("application/json");
        PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();

        for (Vehicle vehicle:vehicles){
            writer.println(vehicle.getVehicleId());
        }
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
```

I get a Hibernate Exception if I try to use it as a web service:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException`

Apparently, somehow, it can't find one of my classes. I can't think of why this is happening. Why would it work if you use a main method, yet crash using the same exact code running it as a web service?

Comment: have you got hibernate jars on your classpath? if you are using maven - post the pom.xml contents

Comment: I think perhaps there is more information needed from you, how are you running it as a webservice?

Comment: I am not using Maven - I have copied and pasted the jars in the lib folder and then added them to the classpath as libraries.

Again, it works if you use the main method. So it sees the right classes.

Comment: The hibernate jars are missing in your classpath

Comment: It is running as a webservice in Tomcat. I have added it to Tomcat from Eclipse. If I try to use the writer to print some text on the screen, it works. There's no problem, the web service works with no errors.

But for some reason, there is this Hibernate exception that happens exclusively when I run it as a Web Service.

Comment: You're right, Jens.

I have created a Dynamic Web Project and I do have a lib folder in the WEB-INF folder. I have created a separate lib folder and put the jars in there (I didn't know exactly how this Dynamic Web Project works).

Now I have copied them in the lib folder in the WEB-INF folder and it works.

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: One more thing: Now it works the first time you run it, but if you try to run it a second time, you get the "HTTP Status 500 - EntityManagerFactory is closed"

`exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed`

Is this because the Hibernate Session is closing? Every time I run it, it should open a new session, I mean it's written in the code. What do you think is the issue here?

In order for it to work again, I have to restart Tomcat.